# Auto incremented day

Tags: google-sheets

I need to fill column with date incremented by one day for the whole year. How to make it in automatic way?

[image]

UPD:

I have `2017-06-12` in `B60`

If I add 24 hrs I still have previous day. Why?

```
=B60+time(24,0,0)
```

[image]

If I add 23 hrs - day increase works.

```
=B60+time(23,0,0)
```

if [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag down the first cell.

Comment: You're right, no need for a formula! If you have existing data in the neighbouring column, you can also double-click the pull-down handle to fill in the dates to the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why

```
=B60+TIME(24,0,0)
```

doesn't work is that times between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 are stored as values between 0 and (nearly) 1. The maximum value that you can get from the TIME function is =TIME(23,59,59) - if you put =TIME(24,0,0) then it rolls back to 00:00:00 which is stored as zero. If you add zero to anything (including a date) you just get the original value.

You need to put in the value for a day which is just 1 so the formula should be

```
=B60+1
```

[See Time Function Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?visit_id=1-636315873567594799-3365821794&hl=en-GB&rd=1)

Answer (score 1):

A1 = start date:

`5/29/2017`

A2 = number of days:

`365`

A4 = formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&A2))+A1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/gvFcUSGcBZA) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28853/google-spreadsheets-add-3-hours-to-date-value-dd-mm-yyyy-000000):

1. Put in A1 the value 30/12/2012 08:15:00
2. Put in A2 the formula: =A1+time(23;59;59)
3. Copy the formula in A2 down as far as you need.

Comment: I have updated my question body with +time(24,0,0) experiment result

Comment: Updated to 23. Thanks